# Docker-ssh non-root path/getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I’m trying to use the gitlab-runner with docker-ssh. Here is how my config.toml looks like:

```
[[runners]]
name = “CI/CD docker-ssh alfa”
url = “https://gitlab.com/”
token = “<SOME_TOKEN>“
executor = “docker-ssh”
[runners.ssh]
user = “myuser”
password = “my password”
[runners.docker]
tls_verify = false
image = “ubuntu:latest”
privileged = false
disable_cache = false
volumes = ["/cache"]
shm_size = 0
[runners.cache]
[runners.cache.s3]
[runners.cache.gcs]
```

But I got this error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.3.0 (d78e9e67)
on CI/CD docker-ssh alfa 1f147b76
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest …
ERROR: Preparation failed: build directory needs to be absolute and non-root path
Will be retried in 3s …
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest …
ERROR: Preparation failed: build directory needs to be absolute and non-root path
```

So I tried to change the build directory and here hows my config.toml file looks like now:

```
[[runners]]
name = “CI/CD docker-ssh alfa”
url = “https://gitlab.com/”
token = “<SOME_TOKEN>“
executor = “docker-ssh”
builds_dir = “/home/myuser/“
[runners.ssh]
user = “myuser”
password = “my password”
[runners.docker]
tls_verify = false
image = “ubuntu:latest”
privileged = false
disable_cache = false
volumes = [”/cache"]
shm_size = 0
[runners.cache]
[runners.cache.s3]
[runners.cache.gcs]
```

But I got this new error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.3.0 (d78e9e67)
on CI/CD docker-ssh alfa 1f147b76
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest …
WARNING: Since GitLab Runner 10.0 docker-ssh and docker-ssh+machine executors are marked as DEPRECATED and will be removed in one of the upcoming releases
Pulling docker image ubuntu:latest …
Using docker image sha256:cd6d8154f1e16e38493c3c2798977c5e142be5e5d41403ca89883840c6d51762 for ubuntu:latest …
ERROR: Preparation failed: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:22: getsockopt: connection refused
Will be retried in 3s …
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Stick with an HTTPS URL, and try fixing instead the error:

```
build directory needs to be absolute and non-root path
```

See [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-set-correct-build-directory/4440/8)

> I was running my CI on an old gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.1.
>
> I update to gitlab-runner 10.8.0 and now it’s ok.

Or [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/merge_requests/706#note_59809287):

> Set `build_dir="C:\\gitlab-runner\\builds"` in the `config.toml`.

Comment: in my case I set builds_dir="/home/gitlab-runner/build" but gives the same connection error

Comment: @SaturninoMateus Using an HTTPS or SSH URL?

Comment: Sorry, which URL are you referring to?